# Twitter RSS feed for start page tweets

Tags: twitter, rss

Is it possible to create an RSS feed for all the tweets listed on the start page at [twitter.com](http://twitter.com)?

In the screenshot below I am referring to the tweets which are listed on the right side of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially no, you can't. Twitter did support RSS feeds once but it was removed. (Which was an idiotic anti-user decision... but I digress.)

There is a workaround though. You can't get a RSS feed of your entire Twitter feed, but you can get RSS feeds for individual users <strike>(but not hashtags)</strike> and hashtags using [this tutorial and Google App Script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feed/28149/) that parses the output of Twitter widgets into a RSS feed.

Comment: Thanks @DrTwox. You can even get a feed for hashtags as they are supported by Twitter widgets.

Comment: @orschiro I didn't know that; I've updated the answer. Thanks!